# cocos2d removeAllChildrenWithCleanup crashes

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i am developing an iphone app and i have a problem when removing all items from a CCMenu. The problem is when the selector of the CCMenuItem is called i remove the item that triggered the selector and the application crashes.

The code (in a CCLayer):

```
 -(void) clearAll
 {
    [popupMenu removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];
 }
 -(void) onButtonClick:(id) sender
 {
    [self clearAll];
 }
 -(void) createButtons
 {
      CCMenuItemImage * menuItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"back_button.png" selectedImage:@"back_button.png" target:self selector:@selector(onButtonClick:)]; 
      [popupMenu addChild: menuItem];
 }
```

Does anyone know why does the application crash and how can i fix this issue?

Thanks

UPDATE:

crash message stack trace:

```
 0x01abaabc in __NSI3 ()
 0x01a9f495 in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()
 0x0006852f in -[CCMenuItem activate] at /***/cocos2d/CCMenuItem.m:128
 0x00068d80 in -[CCMenuItemLabel activate] at /***/cocos2d/CCMenuItem.m:222
 0x00065c24 in -[CCMenu ccTouchEnded:withEvent:] at /***/cocos2d/CCMenu.m:196
 0x01b3ae99 in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] ()
 0x000bb44d in -[CCTouchDispatcher touches:withEvent:withTouchType:] at /***/cocos2d/Platforms/iOS/CCTouchDispatcher.m:268
 0x000bbfa3 in -[CCTouchDispatcher touchesEnded:withEvent:] at /***/cocos2d/Platforms/iOS/CCTouchDispatcher.m:337
 0x000bdd5e in -[EAGLView touchesEnded:withEvent:] at /***/cocos2d/Platforms/iOS/EAGLView.m:330
 0x009d63c0 in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
 0x009d65e6 in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
 0x009bcdc4 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
 0x009b0634 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
 0x03589ef5 in PurpleEventCallback ()
```

Comment: post crash message, but it seems that you are trying to remove item while it in usage.

Comment: yes i suspect this also but the thing is that i am not using the item anymore (unless CCMenu uses it). I have added the crash message to my question.

Comment: this is not crash message. post at least several calls from stacktrace before crash line

Comment: updated the crash stack trace. It crashes in CCMenuItem::activate

Comment: if i remove the popupMenu from its parent and recreate the popupMenu the crash doesnt happen.